# Do energy creatures come in various sexes?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-ds9, star-trek-tos

Other than the Q (who can change their appearance at will, so it's hardly convincing), it seems that "male" and "female" only appear to be functions of physical beings in the Star Trek universe. Are energy beings, such as Organians, Douwd, and Calamarain, etc., above having different "genders"?

True, the Douwd, Trelane, Organians, etc., can appear to be humanoid males, but is the essence of the energy creature a particular gender?

Answer (score 4):

The Companion, the Energy Creature that kept Zefram Cochrane alive in TOS was female. (TOS, Metamorphosis).  It was a major plot point.

The same is true of Sargon and the survivors of the ancient race in TOS Return To Tomorrow, saved in the orbs.  At the end, the one remaining male and female entities become independent of their containers like an energy being.

Answer (score 2):

I would assume that any elemental/ethereal being of a higher dimension would relinquish their gender, because they would no longer have use for such appendages upon such astral planes of existence, for they are among the god form. Therefore making procreation through interaction obsolete.
They choose to reveal themselves as they see fit, nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: Trelane apparently had "parents," however.

Comment: Upon reading this http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Trelane 
My above statement still stands.
Perhaps they appeared to kirk as parents because the Trelane knew he would understand the circumstances better, and thus being a little more forgiving.

Comment: They would relinquish their physical sex, but would they relinquish their gender?

Comment: I think I might be thinking more of a metaphysical technicality, rather than how the Creators of Star Trek may have intended them to be. I am thinking that, since they are elemental beings, as to them having powers to 'shape-shift' or at least project mental images to those around them as being Human, I see them more of a higher life form. Energy is just that, you can mold it to whatever you want it to be, especially if you're a life-form solely of energy.

Comment: @GeistvonPA True; but if they always "want it to be", say, a female form, would it be appropriate to say that they're female, or at any rate feminine?

Comment: What is gender, rather than just a physical appearance, but solely how do you define it other than physical appearance? Just because Someone "Looks" gender specific does not mean they do not act or relate to that physical appearance. Therefore since we do not see the a physical form other than what, lets say the Trelane, transmit upon us, then perhaps they aren't even real in an aspect of physical being. Perhaps they are something of an unforeseen entity that simply projects these images into our brain as something we do understand.

Comment: Bluntly: I do not see why they couldn’t be able to take on gender roles, but keeping in mind, they would still be able to change their gender specifications at anytime. Especially if they are mischievous or looking to do harm. An entity such as this might try to manipulate a male by seducing him as a female form, and vise versa, (The entity might try to intimidate someone by being the same gender) all part of an elaborate scheme for that entity to take over the ship, or simply turn one another against each other. For whatever reason that might be for the entity causing the mayhem.